# dynamic seo url for already existing static title

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am having multiple table which has 100's of rows which has a name field. The name field has content like
`some name`

My current url is

`http://localhost:3000/posts/show/2`

how to convert it into

`http://localhost:3000/some-name`

For dynamic inserting datas i used `friendly url gem` thats fine.

Comment: Try the parameterize method as well, like "John Smith".parameterize => "john-smith". This would be one step for getting nice urls. You could also look for those row names where after parameterize they are the same as what you're looking for, which requires selecting them all. I would start with hash = Hash[ MyModel.pluck( :title, :id ) ] and after that hash = Hash[ hash.map{ |k,v| [k.parameterize, v] } ]. This will get you a nice hash with nice urls and what row id they belong to.

Answer (score 1):

converting into `http:localhost:3000/some-name`  is  possible.
You have to do something like this:

```
get ":row-name" => 'controller#actoin_name', :as => 'row_name'
```

and place it at the end of the route file so that any other action dont get caught on this route. And in the controller action you need to do like this:

```
@row = Row.find(params[:row_name])
```

But this is not a good idea for rails. You should map url like this:

```
resources:rows , :except=> [:show]
 get rows/:row_name => 'rows#show'
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at the [friendly-id gem](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id)

Here is the associated [railscast on it](http://railscasts.com/episodes/314-pretty-urls-with-friendlyid?view=asciicast)

However this would give you URLs like localhost:3000/posts/some-name
If you want to eliminate the posts path you might have to modify the routes to do that.

UPDATE from comments.

You'll have to create a migration. `rails g migration add_slug_to_posts slug:string`

```
class AddSlugToPosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :posts, :slug, :string
    add_index :posts, :slug
  end
end
```

Comment: I have worked on `friendly-id gem` i mentioned. This gem works by inserting slug in database but i don't have slug i need to create it using name without creating any slug. The reason is already i have many records

Comment: It doesn't matter if you already have many records. As the railscast mentions even if you already have existing records (such as the posts) you just have to re-save them to generate the slug. You can do this in the rails console like this. `Post.find_each(&:save)` This will generate the slugs for existing posts.

Comment: Ok i have sub category table which has `name` column and contains `some name` how do i add slug to this table

Comment: And also how to add it in `link_to`